# CasperJS array.push Making Variables Null

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have a custom data type that I am populating, I have verified that data populates correctly but when I try to push it to an array the result is both the array and the custom data type variable are null.  Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
var values = [];
var temp = {};

temp['one'] = rows[i].cells[1].innerText.trim();
temp['two'] = rows[i].cells[2].innerText.trim();
temp['three'] = rows[i].cells[3].innerText.trim();
temp['four'] = rows[i].cells[4].innerText.trim();

values.push(temp);
```

When I output temp before `values.push(temp);` all expected values are present. When outputting either `values` or `temp` after `values.push(temp);` both are null.

Very confused, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Declare array and object like this..

```
var values = [];
var temp = {};
```

Example:

```js
var values = [];
var temp = {};

temp['one'] = 'one';
temp['two'] = 'two';
temp['three'] = 'three';
temp['four'] = 'four';

values.push(temp);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: my apologies, that was a typo in my question, that is how I was declaring them. I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 0):

This was a dumb mistake on my part, nothing to do with the .push but want to answer for anyone else having the problem.

```
var values = [];
```

Was declared outside of any function, I thought I could do this and it would be global but that was a newbie mistake.